# Android : AlarmManager with defined date

Tags: android, alarmmanager

If I set my AlarmManager like this :

```
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), sender);
```

It works and notification is launched as soon as I create it.

But what I want is to launch a notification at a defined date and time but it doesn't work.
Here is some parts of my code :

The time when I want the notification to get launched :

```
Date dateNotif = null;
dateNotif = new Date (mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute);
```

(Variables starting by "m" are integer coming from a DatePicker and a TimePicker. Values can be, for exemple, 2011, 8, 31, 16, 45)

Settings of the AlarmManager :

```
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateNotif.getTime(), sender);
```

I have no mistakes with this but no notification is launched...

But it seems that the emulator doesn't answer anymore few minutes after this.

Thx for your help.

Comment: Timezone issue? Try printing dateNotif.getTime() and compare it to System.currentTimeMillis() to see if you acctually get the time you want from date...

Comment: If I pring dateNotif.getTime(), I obtains numbers like : 61272948180000
And if I print System.currentTimeMillis(), I obtains numbers like : 1314804198248

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that Date expects years since 1900, so when you give it 2011 that is actually the year 3911. Try:

```
dateNotif = new Date (mYear - 1900, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute);
```

Comment: Also note that mMonth should be in the 0 - 11 range.

Comment: Which means that you need to mMonth+1